# Differentiate between unit and integration tests category by parameter with NUnit

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, integration-testing

I have NUnit tests, which are seperated between unit (fast) and integration (slow) tests.

Now I have tests which are once run against a http mock (in which case they are unit tests) and against a real webserver (in which case they are integration tests).

Because the test code only differs in the used http object, I do it like this:

```
    async public Task HttpTest([Values("Real", "Mock")] string httpType)
    {
        var HttpObject = (httpType == "Mock") ? MockObject : RealObject;
        ...
    }
```

This works fine. But now I want to create categories of Unit and Integration tests, because often I only want to run the (fast running) unit tests.

I do not have to do it by category, but I also do not know any other way.

Can I somehow select if I want to run the "Real" and/or the "Mock" tests from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to run all the tests in a test run in the same way, you can specify a run parameter on the command-line, like

```
nunit3-console.exe mytests.dll -p "http=Real"
```

Then you can retrieve the parameter in any tests that need it using

```
var httpParam = TestContext.Parameters.Get("http", "Real");
```

The second parameter in the call is the default value to use if no parameter was supplied on the command-line.

If you do it this way, there is no need for multiple test cases or categories.